# Query AD Password Policy as user

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, password-policy

We have a small application for users to change their password (mostly used on thin clients with published applications and no access to a full desktop to go through the usual steps)

I would like to list the active password policy rules for that user in the application (complexity / min age / max age / min chars / max chars / ...) without having to hard-code these in the application. We're also running some Fine Grained Password Policies so that makes hardcoding the rules unmanageable.

Is there a way in C# for end-users to query the rules for their own applied password policies?

I don't want to validate if the chosen password is valid against these rules but provide a list of the actual rules for that user.